# Persistent Samba Share

Tags: linux, debian, boot, raspberry-pi, cifs

There are hundreds of entries for this - and as far as I can tell I am doing it right.

But it is not working...

I run a latest Raspbian (Debian Wheezy) Distribution on a Raspberry Pi. I have configured a fstab entry for a Samba share on my NAS

```
//medienzimmer/Qmultimedia/Musik /mnt/Musik cifs username=XXX,password=XXX,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,auto 0 0
```

I can easily to "sudo mount -a" and the share gets mounted. But It will never happen persistent after the system boots.

The Raspberry Pi is connected via WLAN to the network. I have cifs-utils installed. Any clues what I am missing here (must be something basic ;)

**Edit:**

This seems to be a prevailing Debian Bug/Regression. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=643651

My fix was using a simple init script:

```
sudo touch /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnas && chmod u+x /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnas
```

Content:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /mnt/Musik
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even know what the `auto` is, but am missing the `_netdev` thing.

I know this has to be a last resource, but in case everything else fails you can do the `mount` from an init.d script making sure it is executed after networking scripts. Am also not hundert percent sure about, but believe custom init.d scripts tend to be put by the system the latter in the init script.

Comment: The _netdev thing did not do the trick :|

Comment: Thanks anyway ;) Such a script should be put in "/etc/network/if-up.d/
". Sort of paradox - since the cifs script responsible for the mounting is already there... Anyway - a simple script with mount -a is working now... Still this seems to be b0rked (http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=643651)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are only missing server IP, 192.168.1.11 for this example:

```
//192.168.1.11/medienzimmer/Qmultimedia/Musik /mnt/Musik cifs username=XXX,password=XXX,_netdev 0 0
```

**ps**. try without charset and file and dir mode first and _netdev, cause I understood you are trying to mount network device.

Comment: "medienzimmer" is the server name. mount -a works - so the missing IP is not the issue. I actually have the same artifact on my Linux Mint Debian machine... So all of this can be related to certain debian bugs: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=643651